# LOG4J: One appender for one logger

Tags: java, log4j

Is it possible to set appender for one logger?
I've found line in example `log4j.properties` file:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq=INFO, stdout
```

but I am curious if it can be done for logger defined by me. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new appender which is only used from your package.

```
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.logger.mycom.mypackage=INFO, A1
```

or

```
log4j.logger.mycom.mypackage.MyClass=INFO, A1
```

or even one logger in a class.

```
log4j.logger.mycom.mypackage.MyClass.LOG1=INFO, A1

Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(getClass().getName()); // doesn't go to A1
Log LOG1 = LogFactory.getLog(getClass().getName()+".LOG1"); // goes to A1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there possibility to set it not for a single package but for a single class?

Comment: Just wondering, what about one Appender for all loggers, which name ends with `.LOG1`? Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know if you can but you can have a logger called `LOG` or `XML` or `DB` which is used by every class.